# Dynamically add embedded ruby with jQuery html

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, erb

I am dynamically loading content into my page using jQuery and Ajax and I would like to attach a Rails link to each object being added. My code to generate the list of data is:

```
$.each(data.recipients, function(index, object){
    $("#recipient-list").append("<div id=\""+ object.id +"\" class=\"recipient-list-item "+ object.recipient_type +"\">" + object.email + "<br/> </div>");
});
```

What I want to achieve is add a link_to that will delete the selected item. ie. `<%= link_to "Remove", delete_mail_recipient_path(object.id), method: :delete, data: {confirm: "You sure?"} %>`

Is it possible to add this code to the page using jQuery or do I need to use html instead? I've seen the use escape_javascript used a few places but as far as I can see that is used in `js.erb` files?

Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I kinda worked around this using jQuery: here's my delete code on the jquery side:

```
// deletes a mail recipient
function delete_recipient(element){
    target = element.attr("target");
    var confirm_delete = confirm("Are you sure you want to remove this recipient?")
    if (confirm_delete){
        $.ajax({
            url: '/delete_mail_recipient',
            type: 'delete',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                id: target
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                if (data.result){
                    console.log(target);
                    $("#"+target).remove();
                }else{
                    alert("Sorry something went wrong when trying to delete that recipient.");
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

    // saves the configuration of the mails recipients
    $('#save-config').click(function(){
        var form = $('form#mail-form');
        var valuesToSubmit = $('form#mail-form').serialize();
        console.log(valuesToSubmit);            // 
        save_mail_configuration(valuesToSubmit, form)
    });
```

And this is the code where I set my id's for the dynamic objects on the page that I want to be able to remove:

```
$.each(data.recipients, function(index, object){
    $("#recipient-list").append("<div id=\""+ object.id + "\" class=\"recipient-list-item "+ object.recipient_type +"\">" + object.email + "<a class=\"remove-recipient\" target=\""+ object.id + "\" > Remove</a><br/> </div>");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Your hunches are correct :)

If you are serving the js file from your controller (and not assets), then you should have access to all the Rails view helpers (link_to, etc). Obviously append `.erb` to the filename so the render call knows to parse it with erb first.

So for example

```
$.each(data.recipients, function(index, object){
   $("#recipient-list").append("<%= link_to "Remove", delete_mail_recipient_path(object.id), method: :delete, data: {confirm: "You sure?"} %>");
});
```

As you said, you might need to wrap the evaluation in `raw` or `escape_javascript`.

But other than that, I would advise you to keep your JS in your assets.
If keeping tracks of all your URLs is a pain maybe keep them in similarly named variable as the url_helpers (i.e. mail_recipient_path ) and reuse them.

P.S. the data-attrs that Rails adds are:

```
data-method="delete" data-confirm="Are you sure?"
```

According to the docs, the usage of link to for ajax links is:

```
link_to("Destroy", "http://www.example.com", :method => :delete, :confirm => "Are you sure?")
# => <a href='http://www.example.com' rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" data-confirm="Are you sure?">Destroy</a>
```

So by using that example you can change the url to reflect the object you want to delete.
But yeah, still gonna have to keep your URL helpers up to date with your JS.

Perhaps wrap them in functions like:

```
var mail_recipient_path;

mail_recipient_path = function(id) {
  return '/mail_recipients/' + id;
};
```

Using it like the URL helpers in rails.

HTH

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, I was just wondering do you have an idea of how to specify the object you want to delete? When I use this data-method="delete" data-confirm="Are you sure?" in my a href, the model that is showing has it's delete method called aswell as the path I specify.

Comment: According to the docs, the usage of link to for ajax links is:

    link_to("Destroy", "http://www.example.com", :method => :delete, :confirm => "Are you sure?")
    # => <a href='http://www.example.com' rel="nofollow" data-method="delete" data-confirm="Are you sure?">Destroy</a>